# Mimic Windows' 'Run' window in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process.start

I would like to mimic the Run command in Windows in my program. In other words, I would like to give the user the ability to "run" an arbitrary piece of text exactly as would happen if they typed it into the run box.

While `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` gets me close, I can't seem to get certain things like environment variables such as %AppData% working. I just keep getting the message "Windows cannot find '%AppData%'..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) method to turn %AppData% into whatever it actually corresponds to.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could also call CMD.EXE, which will expand your environment variables automatically.  The example below will do a DIR of your %appdata% folder, and redirect the stdOut to the debug:

```
        StreamReader stdOut;

        Process proc1 = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.EXE", "/C dir %appdata%");
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc1.StartInfo = psi;
        proc1.Start();
        stdOut = proc1.StandardOutput;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(stdOut.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to limit commands to the command window.